# How can I access KProperty1<T,V> from java class?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I am trying to call a function in Kotlin file from a java code but unable to do so, I can  easily call the function from kotlin using A::a where A is the data class and 'a' is its property
I have a kotlin function -

```
fun ArrayList<Z>.isAnyPropertyValid(kProperty: KProperty1<A,B>){
  // Logic to check if any property is valid
}
```

I can call above function from kotlin using -

```
 list.isAnyPropertyValid(A::a)
```

// Where 'a' is a property of Kotlin data class, like-

```
 data class A( @SerializedName("a") val a : String )
```

How can i call isAnyPropertyValid() from a Java code and what all values to pass in arguments ?

Comment: I would strongly recommend doing this from Kotlin only.

Comment: The class I am calling the utility function is written in Java.

Comment: Sure, but you could have it call a custom Kotlin function.